# akka performance on linux with compilation on windows

Tags: performance, scala, akka

I have Scala IDE setup in my windows machine. when i run my test program on the same machine i get some performance figures.

In order to run the same program on Linux machine, which is an 8 core 32 GB machine, i FTPed the generated class files and scala + akka jars to the Linux machine.

the Linux machine is using Server Edition Java and windows machine is using Client edition Java.

When i run the same program on Linux machine with all the paths set properly, i get poor performance than windows machine.

Why is this so? the program is able to run fine but performs poorly on a higher-end machine and on server edition.

Is it due to compilation and run environment differences? What all i can do to investigate the reason for this behavior.

**EDIT:** The windows env where compilation is done 32 bit, and the java on the linux machine is 64 bit server. does that make any difference to the performance?

Comment: thanks. but my main doubt is that if i have missed something to be put on Linux box. e.g. a jar/lib etc. as  i dont have a proper scala setup on linux box and i am invoking the class file directly with command line wit proper jars in classpath (as in my Scala IDE eclipse env)

Comment: simply put, this should atleast give equal performance as on my windows machine, isn't it?

Comment: yes, is it important to run it via sbt? it is already running with proper classpath, and i have given -Xms2048m -Xmx2048M -X:+UseParNewGC -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode options also

Comment: If your program is really shortliving (e.g. runs for a few seconds) then client config might be faster than server (client mode startup take a lot less time and client enables jit'ing of code earlier).

Comment: Can you provide a sample that can verify your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you post the Java configurations on both machines, i.e. the JVM version and all the flags passed to the `java` command on both environments.

Also, how do you measure the performance, and what values do you get? Is there anything else involved, such as I/O, network traffic etc.? If not, what algorithms are being used in your program? Is it a program that calculates and then terminates, or is it a server program that runs until shut down?

You should put a special focus on memory configuration (as suggested by @alex23) and the `-server` flag. Also, make sure that your Linux environment is using a JVM from the same manufacturer as the Windows environment. Windows typically comes with the Sun JVM, whereas some Linuxes may still have the old Oracle JVM. Try `java -version` on the command line.

Also, instead of comparing the results of a complex program, try a simpler program first. Try to determine the overhead of booting up the JVM, versus the effective runtime of your Java/Scala code.

The idea that a Windows-based build causes performance issues on a Linux machine sounds highly improbable. You can easily check this by compiling your software on the Linux machine and then running it.

Comment: hi, the windows java version: 1.6.0_29   linux java version : 1.6.0_12  does this make any difference? Options used:  -Xms2048m -Xmx2048M -XX:+UseParNewGC -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode

Comment: The versions look okay; they shouldn't make a difference. Maybe you can try some of the other suggestions. Finding out why a machine is slow is not easy, especially with that little detail given.